# Books to study category Grp

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, book-recommendation

I am starting to study in a" serious "way group theory and I am interested to know if anyone of you knows any book where groups are introduced as a category. I've been looking for information, but so far I haven't gotten anything concrete.

Comment: See the recommendations given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097654/group-theory-via-category-theory?rq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you, it has helped me a lot. Do I delete this question?

Comment: So are you interested in groups as special examples of categories (as in the answers to that question), or in the category of groups as an example of a category?

Comment: @ArnaudD. I am interested in how groups "look" from category theory. I have found a book that I think can help me. The book is "algebra chapater 0" by aluffi. What do you think?